# Need recursive function for generating unique combination of strings

Tags: c#, function, recursion

I have some(say 9, no not definite) unique strings from database(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) and I want to create unique combination of these fields to populate the listbox so that user can select single or different combination of these string fields
like 
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,
AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AG,AH,...
ABC,ABD,ABE,ABF,ABG,ABH,ACD,ACE,ACF,ACG,ACH,.....

In C# (win application)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Given that you are preserving order, you will have 2**9 = 512 possible strings generated.  This will seriously test the limits of your users' patience if you put all of these in a listbox for them to pick from.

Answer (score 8):

My first choice would be "use a `CheckedListBox` and let the user make their picks themselves" - this will save their sanity... would you want to look for "ABCEFH" in a long list?).

If you want the strings:
How about just using binary arithmetic? i.e. use a number (bit-length as per the number of elements), and simply keep incrementing, including the set bits each time? So in C#, for example:

```
static void Main()
{
    foreach (string value in GetCombinations(
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
static IEnumerable<string> GetCombinations(params string[] tokens)
{
    ulong max = (ulong) 1 << tokens.Length;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    // test all bitwise combinations
    for (ulong value = 0; value < max; value++)
    {
        builder.Length = 0;
        ulong tmp = value;
        // include the tokens for the set bits
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((tmp & (ulong)1) == 1) builder.Append(tokens[i]);
            tmp >>= 1;
        }
        yield return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

If you want the data in the order per your example, LINQ is helpful:

```
    foreach (string value in GetCombinations(
          "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
        .OrderBy(s=>s.Length)
        .ThenBy(s=>s))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

public class Combination
{
    static int count = 0;

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder("");
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("aabcbd");

    combination(str, out, 0);
    System.out.println("The Count : " + count);
}


// Recursive
static void combination(StringBuilder in, StringBuilder out, int start)
{
    int len = in.length();

    for (int i = start; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (isAppended(in, out, i))
        {
            continue;
        }

        out.append(in.charAt(i));
        count++;
        System.out.println(out);
        combination(in, out, i + 1);
        out.deleteCharAt(out.length() - 1);
    }
}


static boolean isAppended(StringBuilder in, StringBuilder out, int index)
{
    int inCount = 0;
    int outCount = 0;

    int i = 0;
    int len = out.length();
    char ch = in.charAt(index);

    for (i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        if (in.charAt(i) == ch)
        {
            inCount++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (out.charAt(i) == ch)
        {
            outCount++;
        }
    }

    if (inCount != outCount)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is like  counting integers in base 'n' .. should not be difficult.

Comment: But I need Unique combination and not double(AA,BB) or repeated combinations(AB,BA)